# The combo boxes Scopes and Function in Scope, for a .cpp file are not working in VS2008 sp2. Any idea why these combo boxes are not working?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The .cpp file compiles normally, but the `Scopes` combo box does show only 3 of a total of more than 50 classes and structures existing in this file. The `Functions in Scope` combo box doesn't show anything for those 3 classes.

I have a different version of the same .cpp file in another project (same solution) where both combo boxes are working perfectly.

Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

EDIT: The `Scope combo box` keeps showing "Unknown scope" for the vast majority of the class member functions that I click with the left mouse button.

EDIT1: This is a very simplified version of the problem that I'm facing with those 2 combo boxes :

```
class A
{
    int i;
    public:
    A();
    A(int);
    A(short);
};

//  VS2008 -    If I click with the left mouse button in between the brackets below I get
//              in the 2 combo boxes boxes the following results : 

A::A() : i(10) {}           //  A and A()

A::A(short s) : i(s) {}     //  A and A(short)

A::A(int k) : i(k) {}       //  (Unknown Scope)

//  Why the unknown scope ?
```

**Edit3 :  This was a bug in VS2008. It doesn't happen in VS210 !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in VS2008. No more in VS2010 !!

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense is not exactly the most stable feature of Visual Studio for C++...

You can try deleting the .ncb file of your project (it has the same name as the project's .sln file), that contains the intellisense database. When it's missing VS rebuilds it from scratch and everything should be working again.

Comment: I've already done that. Can you tell me if this behavior (see code snippet above) can be reproduced with VS2010 ?